# Perl dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multidimensional-array

In my Perl Programm, I used for testing the following static array definition:

```
my %data = (
    56 => [
        {   'Titel'    => 'Test 1',
            'Subtitel' => 'Untertest 1',
            'Beginn'   => '00:05',
            'Ende'     => '00:50'
        },
        {   'Titel'    => 'Test 2',
            'Subtitel' => 'Untertest 2',
            'Beginn'   => '00:50',
            'Ende'     => '01:40'
        }
    ],
    58 => [
        {   'Titel'    => 'Test 3',
            'Subtitel' => 'Untertest 3',
            'Beginn'   => '00:10',
            'Ende'     => '01:50'
        }
    ],
    51 => [
        {   'Titel'    => 'Test 4',
            'Subtitel' => 'Untertest 4',
            'Beginn'   => '00:05',
            'Ende'     => '00:20'
        },
        {   'Titel'    => 'Test 5',
            'Subtitel' => 'Untertest 5',
            'Beginn'   => '00:20',
            'Ende'     => '00:40'
        },
        {   'Titel'    => 'Test 6',
            'Subtitel' => 'Untertest 6',
            'Beginn'   => '00:40',
            'Ende'     => '01:05'
        }
    ],
);
```

Now I like to change it, to get data from a database. My select returns 5 values: an id (like 56, 58 or 51 in my example) and the values for each Titel, Subtitel, Beginn and Ende.

How can I build the same array construct like in my static example?

Thanks in advance! Best regards
Daniel

Comment: You could do this several ways. What have you already tried doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want it at the end, you need to push your hashref into the arrayref stored at $data{$id}:

```
push @{ $data{$id} }, {
    Titel    => $titel,
    Subtitel => $subtitel,
    Beginn   => $beginn,
    Ende     => $ende,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this. Sorry, it's been a while since I've done perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;



sub dataset2struc { 
  my $result = {};
  foreach my $row (@_) {
   my $id = $row->{'id'};
   my $recref = $result->{$id} || ();
   my @rec = @{$recref};
   delete $row->{'id'};
   push(\@rec, $row);
   $result->{$id} = \@rec;
  }
  return $result;
}

my @dataset = ({"id" => 1, "a" => "b"}, {"id" => 2, "a" => "c"}, {"id" => 2, "a" => "d"});
print Dumper(dataset2struc(@dataset));
```